# Caching in Django

Tags: python, django, caching

I need to implement some caching mechanism in my Python/Django project. Currently our live site is in Heroku cloud.
Which is the best caching mechanism to use i.e 'Local-memory caching' ,'Filesystem caching' or 'Database caching'?  I need to easily implement this in our live heroku cloud environment. One of my friend suggested to use 'python Memcached'. But its really difficult to set up. My time is minimal.

Can anyone advise me on this, please?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You forgot to mention the most important part: **what are you caching**.

Comment: Sorry for that...actually i want to cache the page itself. I'm working on a service site. Actually it does some web scrapping and display the contents scrapped in our own way using the our own design. Either i think of caching the whole page or the result from the database. Please advice..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django has a inbuild Memcache Support which you can use  **https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/cache/**

You will get more info [Here](http://ilian.i-n-i.org/caching-websites-with-django-and-memcached/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Memcached is the right answer. Just take time to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at caching libraries like [cacheops](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops) or [cache-machine](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine).